# Drop down list in grid within iPad/iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I would like to list products in a tableView and once I have those products I would like to have a drop down list with integer values within that grid.  This would look a little like below.  How can I have a dropdown list like control within that grid that would allow the user select an integer value from 0-9?

```
Description    Integer Value     Bool
Product 1      1                 Yes
Product 2      8                 No
```

I don't know the name of the control or how to implement this, any direction is most appreciated.

Comment: The closest thing you can get to a built-in drop down list is a picker view.  Not at all the same as a dropdown, but it is a limited set of selections presented in a list of sorts.  Your "diagram" doesn't very well present the idea you're trying to achieve, at least not to me

Comment: If I use something like the picker view can I touch a control on the screen within the grid and see the picker below and then close the picker?

Comment: It would be possible to add the pickerview to your main view in such a way that it would appear similar to a dropdown from your grid.  I don't know of any samples that use them this way, most of the time the picker view is used to replace the standard keyboard when editing a text field